# Как распарсить экранированный json?

Tags: javascript, json

Помогите пожалуйста распарсить json.

у меня есть сервис, который по определённому адресу отдаёт [следующий](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zlodiak/rurun_front_ng2/master/src/app/test_json.json) json

я одном из js-приложений, я его получаю и работаю с ним(вывожу, используя погинацию). Проблема в том, что это тестовый json, а реальный json выглядит сложнее, приблизительно так:

```
"[{\"model\": \"statistic.article\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"author\": 1, \"title\": \"\\u0414\\u043b\\u044f \\u0435\\u0436\\u0435\\u0439 \\u0445\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430\\u043a\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u043d\\u043e \\u043f\\u043b\\u043e\\u0442\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0442\\u0435\\u043b\\u043e\\u0441\\u043b\\u043e\\u0436\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435\", \"text\": \"\\u0414\\u043b\\u044f \\u0435\\u0436\\u0435\\u0439 \\u0445\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430\\u043a\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u043d\\u043e \\u043f\\u043b\\u043e\\u0442\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435\"}}]"
```

мое js-приложение без проблем работает с первым json, но не работает со вторым json. При этом в консоль выводится следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
core.es5.js:1020ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли каким-нибудь способом обработать проблемный json?

ps: Бекенд у меня на django. Возможно с его стороны нужно обрабатывать

Comment: `JSON.parse()` пробовал?

Comment: работает с `JSON.parse()` , только что проверил, вот только пример "реального" json какой-то не полный...

Comment: webDev_ пробовал parse. не помогло. сообщение об ошибке то же самое

Comment: а вы ответ от сервера точно получаете ? ато такое впечатление что эта ошибка связана не с парсингом json-а, а с самим запросом на сервер

Comment: Rostyslav Kuzmovych, вы правы. посмотрел внимательнее и увидел, что adBlock не разрешал выполнить аякс-запрос. теперь всё ок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что плагин для хрома adBlock почему-то блокировал разрешённый со стороны сервера кроссдоменный запрос